# Unzip File in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, unzip, zip

Can someone help me how to **unzip** a zip file in *VB.Net*?

im using "Imports Shell32"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you take a look at this [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/257193/Easily-zip-unzip-files-using-Windows-Shell32) article it should help you. If you are having specific problems you need to put the code and problem discription in your question.

From above article:

```
Sub UnZip()
    Dim sc As New Shell32.Shell()
    'Create directory in which you will unzip your files .
    IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("D:\extractedFiles") 
    'Declare the folder where the files will be extracted
    Dim output As Shell32.Folder = sc.NameSpace("D:\extractedFiles")
    'Declare your input zip file as folder  .
    Dim input As Shell32.Folder = sc.NameSpace("d:\myzip.zip")
    'Extract the files from the zip file using the CopyHere command .
    output.CopyHere(input.Items, 4)

End Sub
```

link for [`Folder.CopyHere`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866.aspx) Method

---

Or if you are using .Net 4.5 you can use the [ZipFile Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.aspx)

Example from Link:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Compression

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim startPath As String = "c:\example\start" 
        Dim zipPath As String = "c:\example\result.zip" 
        Dim extractPath As String = "c:\example\extract"

        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath)

        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath)
    End Sub 

End Module
```

Comment: @kelvz Next time you choose an answer but there's another good question, at least +1 it.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest that you download http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/ and then use it like this (example taken from the documentation).

```
Dim ZipToUnpack As String = "C1P3SML.zip"  
Dim TargetDir As String = "C1P3SML"  
Console.WriteLine("Extracting file {0} to {1}", ZipToUnpack, TargetDir)   
Using zip1 As ZipFile = ZipFile.Read(ZipToUnpack)   
    Dim e As ZipEntry   
    For Each e In zip1   
        e.Extract(TargetDir, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently)   
    Next  
End Using
```

Comment: my error is "MyExtractProgress"

Comment: @kelvz just remove the AddHandler Line its sole purpose is to give you progress of your extraction. It is a seperate method that is not shown until you look into the vb.net documentation on the dotnetzip codeplex site

Comment: Cannot read that as a ZipFile @MarkHall

Comment: @kelvzy Can not read what as a zip file.